# Cookie slows down my website on first start, always like this?

Tags: php, html, browser, cookies

As soon as I implemented only one cookie into my website, the entire website became very slow on first start.

I guess it's because it is fetching the cookie information. But is this always the case?

There is no heavy code behind fetching the cookie, just plain simple php like this:

```
  $arr = $_COOKIE['name']; // array maximum of 10 values
  one for loop and nothing else!
```

Should I be worried?

With slows down, I mean like loading for 3-5 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: What is inside the "one for loop and nothing else!" ?

Comment: displays the cookie name $i for cookie length. nothing special

Answer (score 2):

This is always the case for the first time. For the second time, browser gets stuff from it's internal cache and temporary files.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving a cookie shouldn't slow your site.  Something else is going on.  You'll need to do some profiling.